# How can I make this corner element raw css/html transition smoother?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

When hovering on the vertical red div I'm trying to make it slide upwards while the horizontal blue div rotates to become a vertical line and follows. It is essential that the two are separated by a corner, and of course this corner should be integrated in the transition.

At the moment my issue is turning the green corner into a straight line. In an attempt to do so I have used the right and bottom borders with a border radius in between to create the corner, and then transitioned the bottom border and border radius to 0. However, this slims the corner before the transition has finished and leaves a small residual on the side, creating an unpleasant visual effect.

The goal is to achieve a smooth transition.
Any alternative solutions are welcome, thank you for your help.

Here is the code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/giacomosaracchi/pen/mdaRvRO).

In case that link doesn't work:

```css
:root {
  --container-height: 150px;
  --container-width: 100px;
}

div.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  
  height: var(--container-height);
  width: var(--container-width);
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.vertical {
  height: 40px;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  
  position: relative;
  left: 98px;
  top: 50px;
  
  transition: top 0.3s ease, height 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}

div.vertical:hover {
  height: 30px;
  top: 40px;
  transition: height 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
}

div.horizontal {
  height: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 100px;
  
  transition: top 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease, left 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

div.vertical:hover ~ div.horizontal {
  width: 30px;
  left: 70px;
  top: 78px;
  
  transition: top 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease, left 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
}

div.corner {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-right: 2px solid green;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  left: calc(100% - 12px);
  
  transition: top 0.3s ease, left 0.3s ease, border-radius 0.3s ease, border-bottom 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease;
}

div.vertical:hover ~ div.corner {
  top: 70px;
  width: 2px;
  left: calc(100% - 4px);
  border-bottom: 0px solid green;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
  transition: top 0.3s ease, left 0.3s ease, border-radius 0.3s ease, border-bottom 0.3s ease-in, width 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="vertical"></div>
  <div class="corner"></div>
  <div class="horizontal"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: I'm not fully understanding the requirement. I note that heights and tops change. But is the green line as it moves to become vertical always to have its left extremity at the same vertical position with the blue line gradually going from horizontal to vertical? Or is the effect supposed to be like a slightly shrinking string being pulled upwards around a fixed point?  [And note there is a jittery effect if the user hovers too low down on the red line.]

Comment: Perhaps experiment with keyframes: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: @AHaworth the animation currently works as intended, aside from the jittering which I am aware of (thanks). The issue I'm having is with the behaviour of the green corner. When you hover it leaves a residual line on the left of the animation, while when you release it displays as slimmer than the other two lines. The red and blue lines work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. If you put all the timings to something long (e.g. 0.3s becomes 30s) you can see the blue line not quite coinciding with the green as it shrinks, and it is 'wobbly' but I guess you aren't concerned about that as it is not really noticeable at 0.3s?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. All I care about is the UX, so as long as the transition is smooth I'm not really concerned with what happens if you slow it down a lot